# Регулярное выражение на извлечение текста пере тэгом

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите подкорректировать регекс выражение.

Выводит "result</div>trash", а мне надо сделать, чтобы выводило "result". Что тут можно задействовать? Вариант с обычным Substring не подходит, а то может быть массив таких вот совпадений.

```
string pattern = "start_(.*)</div>";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
string s = "start_result</div>trash</div>";
Match match = reg.Match(s);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start_(.*?)</div>

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое!